# What is the recommended way(s) to keep track of View state information?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, mvvm, underscore.js

The consensus I've found while reading articles about Backbone seems to be: don't store stuff in the view, store it in the model and then have the view listen for changes on the model.

If we're talking about a situation where we already have an obvious model-view pairing this is great. E.g., You have a User model and a UserView view. Obviously you set a model property on the view and it listens to changes on its model.

However, let's say I have a view that shows a list of stuff, and there are a couple of buttons to switch between 'list view' and 'grid view'. This is a very common convention I see in apps and websites. Whether I want 'list view' or 'grid view' isn't really relevant to the models/collections themselves; it seems very specific to the view itself.

At first I just tried using a view exactly like a model: setting a property, binding an event `'change:propertyName'`, and then using `someView.set('propertyName')`, etc.. to update it... but this didn't work.

While thinking how to approach this, I thought I remembered seeing something like this before:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    model: Backbone.Model(),
    ...
});
```

So, unlike having, let's say, a UserModel.. we just have some 'typeless' model. Or I guess, I could actually create a new class, maybe called `MyViewModel` just for this... although I don't see a reason to.

This allows me to bind to the change event like I had wanted to and set view data with `someView.model.set(...)`.

So my question is: is this a common thing that people do in Backbone for view state? Or is there a better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the selected display style (list vs. grid) to be used whenever the user visits the page? If so, the simplest solution might be to store that state in localStorage, and have the view class access it directly.

If you don't need the current display style to be remembered, then maybe you don't need to store the state at all. Have the style change when a button is clicked. When the page refreshes, it returns to the default.

If your app has logged-in users with accounts, and you want their choice to persist across all devices they may be using, you need to have something like a `UserModel` (which has the logged-in user's info and preferences) that records their choice and saves it to the server. Your view can listen for changes on this model.

The beauty of Backbone (to me) is that there isn't a single right way to do something. These ideas are only some of the ways to can handle it.

You could also have a `displayStyle` property on the collection. I get this idea from sortable tables: in that case, the sort metadata is part of the collection object. When you resort the table by selecting a column heading, you change the collection's `comparator` and resort it. The view will be listening for the "sort" event and re-render when it occurs. You could do something similar for display style (you can create your own events by doing `this.trigger('display-style')` in your collection and having the view listen for that event).

Finally, however you decide to manage that state, you should think about whether this should all be one view class or multiple view classes. I think this would depend a lot on the complexity of your application. In many cases, it might be better to have, say, `ProductListView` and `ProductGridView`, instead of a single `ProductView` with two display styles. Splitting them into separate views might even make it easier to add other styles (`ProductImageView`, maybe?) in the future.